# MySQL: shift data between timestamped rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table looking like this:

```
mysql> explain test_table;
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| timestamp           | datetime    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| id                  | varchar(64) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| px_last             | float       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| twap                | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

For a given symbol and timestamp, I want to shift the value of the field `twap` back one timestep.

This table:

```
mysql> select * from test_table;
+---------------------+-------+---------+-------+
| timestamp           | id    | px_last | twap  |
+---------------------+-------+---------+-------+
| 2011-01-01 00:00:00 | apple |     101 | 101.1 |
| 2011-01-01 00:00:00 | pear  |      50 |  50.1 |
| 2011-01-02 00:00:00 | apple |     102 | 112.8 |
| 2011-01-02 00:00:00 | pear  |      51 |  57.3 |
| 2011-01-03 00:00:00 | pear  |      52 |  59.1 |
| 2011-01-03 00:00:00 | apple |     103 | 104.1 |
+---------------------+-------+---------+-------+
```

should end up like this:

```
mysql> select * from test_table;
+---------------------+-------+---------+-------+
| timestamp           | id    | px_last | twap  |
+---------------------+-------+---------+-------+
| 2011-01-01 00:00:00 | apple |     101 | 112.8 |
| 2011-01-01 00:00:00 | pear  |      50 |  57.3 |
| 2011-01-02 00:00:00 | apple |     102 | 104.1 |
| 2011-01-02 00:00:00 | pear  |      51 |  59.1 |
| 2011-01-03 00:00:00 | pear  |      52 | NULL  |
| 2011-01-03 00:00:00 | apple |     103 | NULL  |
+---------------------+-------+---------+-------+
```

My first approach (using this example: [How to number rows...](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/)) would be to create a row number (1, 2....n) within each symbol, then copy row number, symbol and twap to a temporary table, decrease row number with 1 at each row in the temporary table and then copy the data back to the original table.

Is there a way to do this without creating the temporary table? The table is huge, > 50 million rows and growing, so finding the largest timestamp that is smaller than a given timestamp is not efficient enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
UPDATE test_table tt1
   SET tt1.twap =
        ( SELECT tt2.twap
            FROM ( SELECT timestamp,
                          id,
                          twap
                     FROM test_table
                 ) tt2
           WHERE tt2.timestamp = DATE_ADD(tt1.timestamp, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
             AND tt2.id = tt1.id
        )
;
```

Technically speaking, this *does* create a temporary table (as a workaround for the dreaded [`ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'tt1' for update in FROM clause`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ERROR+1093+%28HY000%29%3A+You+can%27t+specify+target+table+%27%2a%27+for+update+in+FROM+clause%22)), but at least it's all handled implicitly by that inner subquery, rather than requiring you to create one as a separate step.

For a large table, I would not expect this to perform very well, but you can break it into smaller updates by handling just one time-range at a time (provided you start with the earliest time-range and move futureward, so that you never overwrite data you're about to use). Your individual statements would then look like this:

```
UPDATE test_table tt1
   SET tt1.twap =
        ( SELECT tt2.twap
            FROM ( SELECT timestamp,
                          id,
                          twap
                     FROM test_table
                    WHERE timestamp BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2011-01-02 00:00:00'
                                        AND TIMESTAMP '2011-02-01 23:59:59'
                 ) tt2
           WHERE tt2.timestamp = DATE_ADD(tt1.timestamp, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
             AND tt2.id = tt1.id
        )
  WHERE tt1.timestamp BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2011-01-01 00:00:00'
                          AND TIMESTAMP '2011-01-31 23:59:59'
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction and the suggestion! However, the interval will sometimes be more than one day (holidays etc), in which case I expect your solution to break down, right?

Comment: @MånsRolandiDanielsson: Yes, this solution requires the days to be consecutive.